# How to load the URL without prefix (www) in webview android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, url, android-webview

Webview doesn't loads the ***Url format1*** but loads the ***Url format2***. As per my requirement user will be providing the input as *Url format1* any suggestions to fix the issue.

***Url format1:***
bbc.com

***Url format2:***
www.bbc.com

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Webview it is a good practice to using Url format2.

Answer (score 0):

Can you append "www." to the http request. The user inputs bbc.com but www.bbc.com is sent to the server